# Block all signals in OCaml

Tags: unix, signals, ocaml

I want to block all signals in OCaml using `Unix.sigprocmask`. In C, I would do this using the function `sigfillset`, which is not available in the Unix module. So how do I get a list of all signals in OCaml, that I can then pass to `sigprocmask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix.sigprogmask expects 2 arguments : a command, a list of int listing the signals id you wish to block.

`Unix.sigprocmask Unix.SIG_BLOCK (Core.List.init 32 (fun x -> x+1));;`

This will block the 32 signals from 1 to 32.

Comment: I know what arguments Unix.sigprocmask expects. But I want to block *all* signals, so how to get a list of all valid signals?

Comment: I would say Unix has standardized signals https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm - from 1 to 34.

Comment: Thanks, those signal numbers work as expected (I was confused because Sys.sig* are seemingly random negative numbers)

Comment: I had a look at signal.h : sigset_t is generally an integer 32 - but can be 64 also, as some implementations go up to 34 different signals .